# Error appears during installation rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
when i try to install rgbdslam,with the help of this tutorial
(http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam)
after this command :
svn co http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg
this error appear :
Checked out revision 3918.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55284/error-appears-during-installation-rgbdslam/) by [howyda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3699/howyda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is definitely not an error, this is a status message that tells you which revision you checked out. If something goes wrong, post the complete output.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4